# Can't find dependencies for Common Data Service in Powerapps Portal

Tags: powerapps, common-data-service, powerapps-portal

I'm having troubles deleting relationships, columns and tables because of dependencies. I have a test environment setup for a Powerapps portal. When I look for a dependency list under Solutions it comes back with nothing yet I keep getting dependency errors. I've deleted all lists and forms that reference lookup data and removed referenced lookup fields in the views I've changed.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Nathan, this seems like less of a programming question and more of a customer service question for Microsoft. Please review the [topic guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more info.

Comment: Can you add screenshots to understand it better. Show dependency is different from Dependency for delete..